# Call one batch in another inside for loop in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file to read a data from one text file and get the sum of those data. Here I have data in floating point. So I have created the batch file as follows:

```
set LOGFILE=Sample.txt

set /a total=0

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=: " %%a in (%LOGFILE%) do (

call :IntAsFP a=%total%
echo %a%
call :IntAsFP b=%%b
echo %b%
set /a total=a+b
echo %total%
call :IntToFP total=%total% 3
echo %total%

)

goto :EOF

:IntAsFP Int=FP
set FP=%2
set %1=%FP:.=%
exit /B

:IntToFP FP=Int digits
set Int=%2
set %1=!Int:~0,-%3!.!Int:~-%3!
exit /B
```

In this actual problem is that when I use this without for loop that means if I pass the value directly to the second argument, it works fine. When I use for loop to get the data one by one from txt file, it fails: it calls the function but does not return the value properly.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have already enabled delayed expansion but are not using it. Replace strings like

```
echo %total%
```

with strings like

```
echo !total!
```

If you change the value of a variable inside a code block, you have to use exclamation marks, not percent signs, to access it later in the same code block.